# Exclude Qt and Boost includes from CMake dependencies

Tags: qt, boost, dependencies, cmake

Does someone know a way how to exclude all Qt and Boost dependencies from a CMake project?

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude"? Your CMakeLists.txt probably contains FindQt, FindBoost calls you can disable, given that the code doesn't depend on Qt or boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set INCLUDE_REGULAR_EXPRESSIONS ("\.h$"), because my project's header files all end with .h. As Boost ends its header files with .hpp, this excludes the Boost header files. It also helps with Qt at least partially, because Qt has not suffixes at all for the public header files, but uses .h for internally included header files.
However excluding Boost header files gave a huge performance improvement, when scanning header dependencies

Answer (score 2):

I use command `include_regular_expression("^([^b]|b[^o]|bo[^o]|boo[^s]|boos[^t]|boost[^/]).*$")` to skip all includes starting with "boost/" (if somebody knows a simpler regex - please add a comment). Certainly, it may be extended to Qt headers.